# User connection count performed by the same user account logging in

Tags: sql-server

As a user logs on to the database, their session count is checked (run by their own SQL account), for example if user 'qa' is logging on:

```
select COUNT(dbid) from sys.sysprocesses where loginame='qa' group by loginame
```

This always returns a count of 1 even though there are multiple connections of the same user.

If I run the same statement from sa, the count result is correct.  It seems SQL server is not returning a count of all the user's own sessions, except the current one.

Is there a known issue or limitation that a user can't count all of their own sessions?

I'm trying to check login count using a stored procedure; it's run in the same db and as the same user that logs on. In essence the procedure uses the select statement above.

I have tried using `sys.dm_exec_sessions`, and `sys.syslogins` with similar results.

Is there a way for a user to self-check their own login count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure other accounts have access to that view?

Per [BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysprocesses-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
If a user has VIEW SERVER STATE permission on the server, the user will see 
all executing sessions in the instance of SQL Server; 
otherwise, the user will see only the current session.
```

Comment: Yes, thank you.  After granting view server state, it's working. On related note, its noted that sysprocesses will be removed in the future,  sys.dm_exec_sessions is the preferred view.